# Qual o erro com meu script? - setTimeOut

Tags: javascript

Olá!! 
O script abaixo, pega uma imagem de id `assinatura` e aplica um efeito nela quando meu scroll está à certa altura do site.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            $("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello");
        }
    });
```

Porém, eu gostaria de que quando o scroll atingisse 400 ou mais de altura, o programa esperasse 2 segundos para aplicar o efeito que eu queria. (2 segundos para teste).

Então tentei fazer da forma abaixo, mas que resultou na mesma coisa que o anterior, ou seja, o programa só está executando como se não ouvesse o setTimeOut:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            window.setTimeout($("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello"), 5000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No console (F12) poderá ver que o problema é:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

O `setTimeout` espera que o primeiro parâmetro seja uma função ou uma string do código, [veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(func[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
setTimeout(code[, delay]);
```

Dessa forma você tem as seguintes soluções:

**1. Criar uma função anonima:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello")
}, 5000);
```

**2. Criar um função e chama-la:**

```
function animate(){
   $("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello")
}

setTimeout(animate, 5000);
```

> Se função exigir algum argumento você pode informar o valor após o `delay`.

**3. Tornar uma string para um eval():**

```
setTimeout('$("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello")', 5000);
```

> Essa [solução não é recomendada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) e variáveis locais não podem ser acessadas.

Comment: Não gosto da idéia de você dizer "como" arrumar mas não dizer "o que está errado" e por que.  O OP agora vai decorar que tem que colocar o "function" em volta de sua chamada, e achar que é mágica.

Comment: Dei uma melhorada e acrescentei a possibilidade sem a necessidade do `function`.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta substituir este trecho:

```
if (scroll >= 400) {
    window.setTimeout($("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello"), 5000);
}
```

por

```
if (scroll >= 400) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#assinatura").addClass("animated jello")
    }, 5000);
}
```

Ocorre que o parâmetro do `setTimeout` recebe uma função, e com seu código, você está chamando a função `addClass` imediatamente e passando o retorno dela.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que passar uma função e para o setInterval ou setTimeout. Ex:

```
setInterval(function(){ /*Minha declaração*/ },1000) ou setInterval(() => {/* Minha declaração */},1000)
```

Comment: O `setInterval` e `setTimeout` são funções completamente distintas, o `setInterval` irá executar a função a cada 1 segundo e não apenas após 1 segundo. :S